# salt-stack - 'onchange' directive misunderstood or ignored?

Tags: yaml, salt-stack

I'm trying to write one of my first states:

```
custom:
  pkg.installed:
  - sources:
    - custom_repo: http://yum.custom.com/custom_repo.noarch.rpm
  - require:
    - pkg: epel
  cmd.run:
  - name: rpm --import http://yum.custom.com/RPM-GPG-KEY
  - onchanges:
    - pkg: custom
```

But the `cmd.run` keeps executing, even though there is the `onchanges` directive. So from my understanding, if the package is present, the `cmd.run` module should not be executed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to @alejdgs** editation, I was able to fix my problem...

it simply wasn't 'onchange', but 'onchanges'

Now I'm going to dig a deep hole and never come out again. Jeez I'm blind.

Comment: What I find strange is, that salt didn't warn me about wrong syntax